# IntelliJ code inspection tells me a selector is never used. Why?

Tags: css, reactjs, intellij-idea, code-inspection

I have a .js script using React, and a .css file. In the JavaScript, there's this snippet:

```
render() {
        return (
            <select id='type_selection' ref='select' onChange={this.filter}>
                <option selected>All Issues</option>
                <option>Production</option>
                <option>Staging</option>
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

In the style sheet, there's this snippet:

```
#type_selection {
  background-color: lightblue;
  color: black;
  font-size: 80%;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

When I run "Inspect Code" in Intellij, it tells me that the selector `type_selection` is never used. What can be the reason for this? Both files are in the same directory.

Comment: have you imported the css file to js file?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this. In the JS, there's this line too:
`import './App.css';`